# Trouble with 1602 LCD display displaying additional decimal points using a raspberry pi pico and DHT22 sensor as a weather station

Tags: temperature, lcd, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm still new at coding and was able to put together some code from other sources for a simple weather station I built.  Everything seems to be working fine but I do get the occasional hiccup where temperature readings on the display show additional decimals points beyond 0.1-0.9. I inserted a round command to round to the nearest decimal which I thought would take care of that but it still happens randomly.  There are no issues when displaying temperature readings through the shell. It seems to add additional decimal points at random temperature readings just on the display. I've included pictures and code. Definitely would appreciate any help I can get figuring out this issue. Thank you.

```
from machine import Pin
import utime as time
from pico_i2c_lcd import I2cLcd
from machine import I2C
from DHT22 import DHT22

i2c = I2C(id=1,scl=Pin(27),sda=Pin(26),freq=100000)
lcd = I2cLcd(i2c, 0x27, 2, 16)
dht_data = Pin(15,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
dht_sensor=DHT22(dht_data,Pin(14,Pin.OUT),dht11=False)

while True:
     T,H = dht_sensor.read()
    #Converted to Fahrenheit (FT) for LCD display
    FT = T*1.8+32
    if T is None:
        print(" sensor error")
    else:
        print("{:3.1f}'C  {:3.1f}%".format(T,H))
    #DHT22 not responsive if delay too short
    time.sleep_ms(500)
    
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.move_to(0,0)
    lcd.putstr('Temp:')
    lcd.move_to(10,0)
    #If using Celsius, change (FT) to (T) and "F" to "C" on line below
    lcd.putstr(str(round(FT, 1))+"F")
    lcd.move_to(0,1)
    lcd.putstr('Humidity:')
    lcd.move_to(10,1)
    lcd.putstr(str(H)+"%")`
```

[what it normally looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc49V.jpg)

[the hiccup that randomly appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvuR4.jpg)

Comment: `lcd.putstr('{5.1f} F'.format(FT))`